# MpAndroid chart Android - How to remove horizontal highlight Indicator

Tags: android, charts, mpandroidchart

I am using MpAndroid for chart in Android.
When I touch any point in chart two line are drawn on chart(Vertical and Horizontal highlight Indicators).
1 line parallel to X axis(Horizontal Indicator) and another parallel to Y Axis(Vertical Indicator).
I want to show only Vertical Indicator.
How can I do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is a method for a DataSet (e.g. CandleDataSet)

```
candleDataSet.setDrawHorizontalHighlightIndicator(false);
```